# Trying to create a discord bot with Discordia and Lua but the kick command keeps crashing it

Tags: lua, discord, luajit, luvit

I'm trying to write a Discord bot with Lua and the Discordia library. I've been trying to implement a way for it to check whether the person running the command has a role to do so. The id for that role is the `adminid` variable. The bot was working until I implemented the permissions check and now it crashes with

`Uncaught Error: .../Documents/Lua Projects/DiscordBot/deps/coro-channel.lua:62: ...rojects/DiscordBot/deps/discordia/libs/utils/Emitter.lua:105: ...cts/DiscordBot/deps/discordia/libs/containers/Member.lua:312: attempt to index local 'self' (a number value) stack traceback: [C]: in function 'assert' .../Documents/Lua Projects/DiscordBot/deps/coro-channel.lua:62: in function 'onPlain' ...s/Lua Projects/DiscordBot/deps/secure-socket/biowrap.lua:76: in function <...s/Lua Projects/DiscordBot/deps/secure-socket/biowrap.lua:61> [C]: in function 'run' [string "bundle:/init.lua"]:52: in function <[string "bundle:/init.lua"]:47> [C]: in function 'xpcall' [string "bundle:/init.lua"]:47: in function 'fn' [string "bundle:deps/require.lua"]:310: in function <[string "bundle:deps/require.lua"]:266>`
whenever you run the command. I have no idea what the problem is so I'm asking you guys. Here's my full code if anyone can help me out.

```
local discordia = require("discordia")
local coro = require("coro-http")
local json = require("json")
local client = discordia.Client()

adminid = 726406258730598451

local commands = {
    {Command = "-ping", Description = "Replies with pong!"};
    {Command = "-norris", Description = "Replies with a Chuck Norris fact!"};
    {Command = "-cool [mentionedUser]", Description = "Says how cool the mentioned use is! If no one is mentioned it replies with how cool you are!"};
}

function chuckNorris(message)
    coroutine.wrap(function()
        local link = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random"
        local result, body = coro.request("GET", link)
        body = json.parse(body)
        message:reply("<@!"..message.member.id.."> "..body["value"])
        
    end)()
    
end

client:on("messageCreate", function(message)
    local content = message.content
    local member = message.member
    local memberid = message.member.id
    if content:lower() == "-ping" then
        message:reply("pong")
        
    end
    if content:lower() == "-norris" then
        chuckNorris(message)
        
    end 
    if content:lower():sub(1,#"-cool") == "-cool" then
        local mentioned = message.mentionedUsers
        if #mentioned == 1 then
            message:reply("<@!"..mentioned[1][1].."> is "..math.random(1,100).."% cool.")
            
            elseif #mentioned == 0 then
            message:reply("<@!"..memberid.."> is "..math.random(1,100).."% cool.")
            
        end
        
    end
    if content:lower() == "-help" then
        local list = ""
        for i,v in pairs(commands) do
            list = list..v.Command..": "..v.Description.."\n"
            
        end
        message:reply(list)
        
    end
    if content:lower():sub(1,#"-ban") == "-ban" then
        local mentioned = message.mentionedUsers
        if #mentioned == 1 then
            message:reply("<@!"..mentioned[1][1].."> has been banned.")
            member.guild:banUser(mentioned[1][1],_,_)
            
            elseif #mentioned == 0 then
            message:reply("Error: Incorrect Syntax = -ban [user]")
            
            elseif #mentioned >= 1 then
            message:reply("Sorry that operation isn't supported yet.")
            
        end
        
    end
    if content:lower():sub(1,#"-unban") == "-unban" then
        local mentioned = message.mentionedUsers
        if #mentioned <= 1 then
            message:reply("<@!"..mentioned[1][1].."> has been unbanned.")
            member.guild:unbanUser(mentioned[1][1],_)
            
            elseif #mentioned >= 1 then
            message:reply("Sorry that operation isn't supported yet.")
            
        end
        
    end
    if content:lower():sub(1,#"-kick") == "-kick" then
        local mentioned = message.mentionedUsers
        if member.hasRole(adminid) == true then
            if #mentioned <= 2 then
                message:reply("<@!"..mentioned[1][1].."> has been kicked for ")
                member.guild:kickUser(mentioned[1][1],_)
                
                elseif #mentioned == 0 then
                message:reply("Error: Incorrect Syntax = -kick [user]")
                
                
                elseif #mentioned >= 2 then
                message:reply("Sorry that operation isn't supported yet.")
                
            end
        else
            message:reply("You do not have permission to run that command.")
        end
    end
        
end)

client:run("Bot "..io.open("./login.txt"):read())
```

Comment: you have a function call with `.` where you're supposed to use `:` and your first parameter is a number value. in that function this makes self a number value where it is supposed to be a table. anything else can be obtained from the call stack. happy debugging

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a function using the `.` operator, instead of the `:` operator, this causes the first parameter of the called function (known as `self`) to be invalid. This is because when you call `thing:function(parameter)`, lua actually calls `thing.function(thing, parameter)`. The error message states that `self` (which is the variable name commonly used for this first parameter), was indexed (like `self[2]` or `self.b`), but self was a number value (`adminid`).

To fix this simply change

```lua
if member.hasRole(adminid) == true then
```

to

```lua
if member:hasRole(adminid) == true then
```

Additionally, testing `== true` is not necessary because it will only return `true` if the right side it `true`, which does nothing (unless your testing for specifically the `boolean` type, but this is usually not the case).

Answer (score 0):

If you continue needing the answer. 
Change `message.member` to `message.author` 
 this will return the user, to get the member do (for a guild) `message.guild:getMember(author or author.id)`